# Need to highlight required area using leaflet

Tags: openstreetmap, leaflet, point-in-polygon, leaflet-draw

I need to display a polygon and highlight a city, I added the link bellow

https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search.php?q=Bambalapitiya&polygon=1&viewbox=

as `nominant` search I need to highlight a city using leaflet java-script library. 
Help me with this.

Comment: Please EDIT your question and tell us what tutorial on http://leafletjs.com/examples.html you have already tried, and why each of them did NOT work for you. Especially "Using GeoJSON with Leaflet" should come your aim, or not?